# Updating Datagrid datacontext eats memory

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a WPF datagrid and I need to update it every minute. I have added a DispatchTimer to get the data and update the data Context of my datagrid. The problem is that it seems like data is sticking around. First I was thinking it was my lists but I just had the lists running with out updated my dataContext and I don't see the megs of memory being used.

```
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

I have it set to 1 second for testing.

```
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Technician> techData = LoadData();
        DG1.DataContext = null;
        DG1.DataContext = techData;
    }
```

...

```
    private ObservableCollection<Technician> LoadData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Technician> techData = new ObservableCollection<Technician>();

        Uri uriGreenImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/green.png");
        Uri uriRedImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/red.png");

        // Connect to Database.
        Database db = new Database();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.StatusBoard ORDER BY dbo.StatusBoard.LastName";

        SqlDataReader reader = db.Query(query);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            BitmapImage statusImage;

            switch(reader["Status"].ToString())
            {
                case "0":
                    statusImage = new BitmapImage(uriGreenImage);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    statusImage = new BitmapImage(uriRedImage);
                    break;
                default:
                    statusImage = new BitmapImage(uriRedImage);
                    break;
            }

            techData.Add(new Technician
            {
                FullName = reader["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + reader["LastName"].ToString(),
                Comments = reader["Comments"].ToString(),
                Status = statusImage,
                WatchingServiceDesk = (reader["WatchingServiceDesk"].ToString() == "1" ? true : false),
                Phone = reader["Phone"].ToString()
            });
        }

        return techData;
    }
```

Comment: Try to locate the actual problem first...

Comment: Well I figured it out. I moved the new calls for BitmapImage out and just made one instance of them. After that I changed the LoadData method to update techData and not return anything. I would then update the DataContext with techData. I think the problem was that every tick I was making a new instance of ObservableCollection<OBJECT> along with new BitmapImages... GC may would have caught up soon enough but I was using up to much RAM to tell.